# perl match and remove number of lines

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a line and delete a few lines after it(including the matched one) from some files. The thing is my code works when I put one single file but when I try to do *.tcl for example, it doesn't do anything. Can you advice? Thanks

```
 perl -i -ne '$n=12 if?$match?;print unless$n-->0' *.tcl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the section on `m??` in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in detail:

> - `m?PATTERN?msixpodualgc`
> - `?PATTERN?msixpodualgc`
>
>   This is just like the [`m/PATTERN/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) search, except that it matches only once between calls to the [`reset()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reset.html) operator. This is a useful optimization when you want to see only the first occurrence of something in each file of a set of files, for instance. Only [`m??`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) patterns local to the current package are reset.
>
>   ```
>      1.     while (<>) {
>      2.         if (m?^$?) {
>      3.                          # blank line between header and body
>      4.         }
>      5.     } continue {
>      6.         reset if eof;    # clear m?? status for next file
>      7.     }
>   ```
>
>   Another example switched the first "latin1" encoding it finds to "utf8" in a pod file:
>
>   ```
>      1.     s//utf8/ if m? ^ =encoding \h+ \K latin1 ?x;
>   ```
>
>   The match-once behavior is controlled by the match delimiter being `?`; with any other delimiter this is the normal [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) operator.
>
>   For historical reasons, the leading [`m`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) in [`m?PATTERN?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) is optional, but the resulting `?PATTERN?` syntax is deprecated, will warn on usage and might be removed from a future stable release of Perl (without further notice!).

As you can see, this talks about and demonstrates the need to use [`reset`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reset.html) when processing multiple files.  It also suggests always including the `m` operator, as the other syntax is deprecated.

I would therefore rewrite your code to the following:

```
perl -i -ne '$n = 12 if m?$match?; print if --$n < 0; reset if eof' *.tcl
```

Answer (score 3):

`m??` matches only once. If you want to reset it for each file, you should add

```
reset if eof
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *how much* is correct the next:

```
perl -ne 'reset if eof;print unless((m?$patt? and $.=1)..12)' *.txt
```